# Float64 to float in python

Tags: python, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm publishing Float64 type msg via rosserial python node to ros and I want to subscribe those messages. But the python code that subscribing Float64 msgs gives error and now I Float64 cannot convert to float.. Is there any way to do this? I tried with strings and convert it to float. But it failed.

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('UWU_Bot')
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg  import Twist
from std_msgs.msg       import Float64

def callback(volt):
    Distance = 16.2537*volt**4 - 129.893 * volt**3 + 382.268 * volt**2 - 512.611 * volt + 306.439

def nav():
    rospy.init_node('UWU_Bot')
    pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist)
    rospy.Subscriber("/IR_volts", Float64 , callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        nav()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException: pass
```

This is the python code.
And I used rosserial IR_ranger example to send the Float64 data.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122286/float64-to-float-in-python/) by [Hasitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/8076/hasitha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2014-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2014-01-24**:
This is hard to debug without your code. Can you post your code?

**Comment by [Hasitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/8076/hasitha/) on 2014-01-24**:
I edited the post and added the python code

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-25**:
What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message contains the float64 member data that you need to use, i.e. replace `volt` with `volt.data`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hasitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/8076/hasitha/) on 2014-01-25**:
Thank you. It worked for me.